# Prove triangle GIH is isosceles...

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

The geometry questions goes like this:

Let A, B, C and D be four distinct points such that line segments BD and AC are of equal length. let E and F be the midpoints of line segments BC and AD respectively.

Let the intersection of lines EF and BD be H, the intersection of lines EF and AC be G and the intersection of lines BD and AC be I.
Prove triangle GIHis isosceles.

I have a diagram in geogebra below (I don't know how else to present it).

The problem can definitely be solved by coordinate geometry, but I can't seem to find a solution without it.

[image]

Comment: Draw parallelogram ABDJ and connect J with C and B

Comment: Thanks, solved it with just a few steps of coordinate geometry at the end to prove that lines EF and JC are parallel. I should have known to draw a parallelogram earlier. Nice insights.

Comment: @Aqeel I guess the hint given is mainly meant for solving the problem via Euclidean geometry.

Comment: I do know that, but I wasn't sure how to prove the last bit with purely Euclidean geometry (or perhaps I was just too sleep deprived to do so). Still, @IvanKaznacheyeu suggestion massively simplified the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Expanded version of my comment

[image]

ABDJ — parallelogram. AJ is equal to BD, then ACJ is isosceles triangle with AJ = AC. Then angle AJC is equal to angle ACJ.

Diagonal BJ and diagonal AD intersects in middle of AD which is F. Then F is middle of BJ. Then EF is middle line of triangle BCJ. Then EF is parallel to CJ. Then angle IGH is equal to angle ACJ.

IH is parallel to AJ and GH is parallel to CJ, then angle IHG is equal to angle AJC which is equal to angle ACJ which is equal to angle IGH. Angles IHG and IGH are equal, then triangle IGH is isosceles.

Comment: Elegant answer, and much shorter than I expected.